# Swashbuckle custom schema for each method

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, swashbuckle

I am having API method which requires object of class like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have two API calls > `Insert` and `Update`

`Insert` method requires only `Name` from that object but `Update` needs `ID` also.

What I want to achieve is to somehow hide `ID` from schema displayed under function inside swagger for function `Insert` but show it under `ID`.

Schema I am talking about is inside picture:
[image]

I can hide `ID` from everywhere by adding `[JsonIgnore]` but it doesn't solve my problem since I want to show that field inside `Update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per best practices ([*separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)), I would encapsulate your database logic & expose your models as 2 separate DTOs for insert and update operations.

Something like:

`MyObjectCreateDto.cs`

```
public class MyObjectCreateDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`MyObjectUpdateDto.cs`

```
public class MyObjectUpdateDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use the above models for your endpoints, which Swagger will pick up on.